# Class Constructor arguments C++

Tags: c++, class, constructor, arguments

I am creating a pair1 class for a x and y Cartesian coordinate system. x and y are doubles. I need to have 3 constructors.

1. No arguments, defaults x and y to zero.
2. One arguement assigns x and defaults y to zero.
3. One arugeument defaults x to zero and assigns y. I'm not sure if I am setting up the class right. I get the follwing error: `pair1::pair1(double)` and `pair1::pair1(double)` cannot be overloaded.

My class:

```
class pair1
{
private:
    double x;
    double y;

public:
    pair1(){ x = 0.0, y = 0.0; }    
    pair1( double a ){ x = a; y =0.0; }
    pair1(double b){ x = 0.0;  y = b; }
};
```

Comment: You have two ctors with the same signature. If I call pair1(3.1), which one should run?

Comment: How about using a simple `std::pair<double, double>`?  You could just initialize it like `x(1.2, 0)` or `x(0, 4.3)` or `x()`. That'd be way more efficient than your code (e.g. why aren't you using initializers?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) no arguments, defaults x and y to
>   zero.

That's easy

> 2) one arguement assigns x and
>   defaults y to zero.
>
> 3) one arugeument
>   defaults x to zero and assigns y.

That's a problem. How do you know, when you only have one parameter, which of the two is meant to be called? That's why you get a compilation error.

Instead - use the default constructor (the one with no parameters), full constructor (the one with both), if needed, and `SetX()` and `SetY()` to set the X and Y separately, and make distinction by the name of the function.

```
class pair1
{
    private:
    double x;
    double y;

    public:
    pair1( double a=0.0, double b=0.0 ){ x = a; y =b; };
                     // default value 0.0 allows to only
                     // set x, and leave y to be the default,
                     // or leave them both default.
    void SetX(double a) { x=a;};
    void SetY(double b) { y=b;};
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the compiler has no way to distinguish

```
pair1(double a)
```

and

```
pair1(double b)
```

Indeed, they are the same thing except for the name of the parameter.  For example:

```
pair1 myPair1(123.456); // Which constructor should be called?
```

This is called *ambiguous overloading.*

Comment: So would I use only one for both? I'm kind of lost right now. I have functions within the class, such as 1.assign()- assigns x and y values. 2. setx()- sets the x vaule and sety() that sets the value. would using these help?

Comment: @Stephen Yes.  The most intuitive thing to do would be to provide a default constructor that initializes both values to zero, as you have done, and provide a constructor that takes two parameters and initializes both values.

Answer (score 1):

```
pair1( double a ){ x = a; y =0.0; }
pair1(double b){ x = 0.0;  y = b; }
```

These are exactly same constructor. Different parameter name doesn't make any difference. All that matters for *overloading* is, the *type(s)* and *number* of types, and their *ordering*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that having default arguments except for the (0,0) case is of any use, but something like this could work:

```
struct X
{
    double value;
    explicit X(double v) : value(v) {}
};

struct Y
{
    double value;
    explicit Y(double v) : value(v) {}
};

class pair1
{
    private:
        double x;
        double y;

    public:
        pair1() : x(0.0), y(0.0) {}
        explicit pair1(X a) : x(a.value), y(0.0) {}
        explicit pair1(Y b) : x(0.0), y(b.value) {}
        pair1(X a, Y b) : x(a.value), y(b.value) {}  // For completeness
        pair1(Y b, X a) : x(a.value), y(b.value) {}  // For super-completeness
        pair1(double a, double b) : x(a), y(b) {}
};
```

Use:

```
pair1 aPair(X(2.0));                 // default y
pair1 anotherPair(Y(4.875));         // default x
pair1 aThirdPair(X(1.0), Y(1.0));
pair1 aForthPair(Y(100.0), X(1.0));  // keyword arguments ;-)
pair1 quintus(23.0, 45.6);
```